# How to create an empty dataframe in Spark 1.6.2 given an example of Spark 2.0.0?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there the way to substitute this line of code to be able to execute it with PySpark version 1.6.2, not 2.0.0? The problem is that `SparkSession` does not exist in Spark 1.6.2.

```
cfg = SparkConf().setAppName('s')
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().config(conf=cfg).getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([], schema=StructType([StructField('id', StringType()),
                                                         StructField('pk', StringType()),
                                                         StructField('le', StringType()),
                                                         StructField('or', StringType())]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For older versions of Spark (earlier versions than 2.0), you can use `HiveContext` instead of `SparkSession`, see the relevant [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html). Small example of setting up the environment:

```
from pyspark import HiveContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('s')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
```

After this you can create a dataframe in the same way as before by using the `sqlContext` variable.

Comment: `SQLContext` should also do the job

Comment: @desertnaut Correct, `HiveContext` is a superset of `SQLContext`. As long as none of the additional features are required `SQLContext` can be used as well. Since the code in the question contained `enableHiveSupport()` I only included `HiveContext` in the answer.